# Xamarin Forms Background Service

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am doing some background services in Xamarin Forms but the Perform Fetch is not Calling even I had enable background mode. Anyone know when it calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application :

> Deprecated
>
> For apps supporting iOS 13 and higher use BGAppRefreshTask.

Comment: so what is the value of setminimumbackgroundfetch interval?? any idea about it??

Comment: @Charmy as said above unless you make specifically app for iOS 12 or lower which is less than 5% of users you should forget perform fetch, it is not working anymore. If you are interested for theoretical purposes find the documents on the Apple's site it is very easy.